# Is possible use Microsoft Graph API in a UWP app on HoloLens in order to initiate a video call through Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, hololens, microsoft-graph-teams, mrtk

I would like to use Microsoft Teams to start a video call using HoloLens device with another people (using a PC).

I have and UWP app that I can install on HoloLens device, I would like to use Microsoft Teams to start a video call, to stablish a communication between HoloLens user and Pc user.
The problem is that I cannot install Microsoft Teams on HoloLens Device.

I have reviewed that exist **[Remote assist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/remote-assist/overview-hololens#:%7E:text=When%20you%20use%20Microsoft%20Dynamics,way%20you%20interact%20with%20holograms.)** but I need a subscription to use it, so I wondering if using **Microsoft Graph API** in a HoloLens's UWP app, I will can initialize a video call through Microsoft teams. Will it be possible to do it?

I see that I can create a Call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
but,

- Do I need a bot? why?
- Do I need access to Azure Active Directory?
- If on HoloLens device I Cannot install Microsoft Teams, Can I stablish a video call with the user using the Microsoft graph API?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We are checking this internally. We will inform you once we have any update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [create a call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using an Graph API.

When a call is created need to mention the requestedModalities where audio/video/videoBasedScreenSharing can be define for a call. please check the properties in [Call resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) .

**You need to create a calling bot for creating
call.**

**To create a bot you need access to Azure Active Directory.**